# TeamViewer8 infinite loop on startup, never shows up

Tags: arch-linux, wine

Using latest stuff from the ArchLinux repositories and got the following packages installed:

- dotnet2
- ntlm_auth (installed from samba)
- winetricks
- smbclient

This is what it throws on console and then infinite loops:

```
$ teamviewer 

Init...
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer...
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"MountMgr" failed to start: 2
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"PlugPlay" failed to start: 2
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000100, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:resource:GetGuiResources (0xffffffff,0): stub
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32dc60,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",0,0x32d918,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x32dc60,0x00000000), stub!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issues in the past, you can get around it by downloading it from the official site, http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx for some reason running it under wine causes wineserver to run out of resources (memory leak perhaps?).

You can run the official Linux version straight from the directory, you don't have to use package manager and it's a lot more stable.

Comment: Thanks, i'll mark your answer as the correct one since I'm not actually satsified with my solution.

Comment: Appreciated, glad to be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing the following:

```
sudo systemctl stop teamviewerd
sudo systemctl disable teamviewerd
sudo systemctl enable teamviewerd
sudo systemctl start teamviewer
sudo teamviewer
```

Maybe it needed to be run as root.